# INFORMATICA LOADING ERROR

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am newbie to informatica.
I am using INFORMATICA 9.1.0 and oracle 11g as source and target database.
I tried to create one table in target database and tried to load data from source to target.
Table is getting created in target database. and I created mapping and workflow which is valid and i start work flow but it gave me following error.

Message Code **RR_4036**

Message

**Error connecting to database [ Arun
 ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
 Database driver error...
 Function Name : executeDirect
 SQL Stmt : Arun
 Oracle Fatal Error
 Database driver error...
 Function Name : ExecuteDirect
 Oracle Fatal Error
 ].**

please help me with good solutions.

Comment: Can you paste full error message from the log?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this.

Previously while creating remote connection in Relational Connection Editor for a session, In code page option i chose "**UTF-8 encoding of unicode**". Now i changed to "**ms windows latin 1 (ansi) superset of latin1**" and I restarted the workflow which is succeeded.

The following video link shows how to create relational connection for a session.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM2d-IHfRUw